# How to make a Many2One constraint in odoo 10

Tags: constraints, odoo-10, fleet

I'm working with Odoo 10, and I'm trying to modify the fleet module like the next image

[image: fleet module]

We need the field "Conductor" (Driver) be unique, I mean, a vehicle only can have assigned one driver and the driver can't have more than one vehicle assigned.

I used this code:

```
@api.constrains('driver_id')
    def _check_driver(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.driver_id in self:
                raise ValidationError("Driver already has a vehicle assigned")
```

but that code doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your could apply a domain filter in the field definition as following

```py
#definition on the fleet.vehicle model
driver_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', index=True, required=True,
    ondelete='cascade', domain=[('vehicle_id', '=', False)])

#definition on the res.partner model
vehicle_id = fields.One2many('fleet.vehicle', 'driver_id')
```

or as following:

```py
@api.constrains('driver_id')
def _check_driver(self):
    FleetVehicle = self.env['fleet.vehicle']
    for record in self:
        if record.driver_id in self:
            vehicle_count = FleetVehicle.search_count(['driver_id', '=', record.driver_id])
            if vehicle_count > 0:
                raise ValidationError("Driver already has a vehicle assigned")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_sql_constraints = [
        ('driver_unique', 'UNIQUE(driver_id, )',
         'The Driver has been already assigned to a vehicle !'),
    ]
```